# Computing expectations by integrating survival function

Tags: probability, expectation

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{E}(\text{max}(X-u,0))=\int_u^\infty(x-u)dF_X(x)=\int_{u}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx$

for $X$ positive r.v. and $u>0$.

I already know how to prove that $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F_X(y))dy$

and here I show my first approach which I would like to know if it's correct, which goes in the opposite direction of the above equality:

$\mathbb{E}(\text{max}(X-u,0))=\int_{u}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx=\int_{u}^{\infty}\mathbb P(X>x)dx=\int_u^\infty\int_u^\infty1_{\{z>x>u\}}\mathbb{P}(X\in dz)dx=\int_u^\infty\int_u^\infty1_{\{z>x>u\}}dx\mathbb{P}(X\in dz)=\int_u^\infty\int_u^zda\mathbb{P}(X\in dz)=\int_u^\infty(z-u)\mathbb{P}(X\in dz)=\int_u^\infty(z-u)dF_X(z)$

I tried with a second way which I report here but I am having more troubles because I am not sure of where to integrate:

$\mathbb{E}(\text{max}(X-u,0))=\int_u^\infty(x-u)f_X(x)dx=\int_u^\infty\int_0^{x-u}1f_X(x)dydx=\int_u^\infty\int_{y-u}^\infty f_X(x)dxdy=\int_u^\infty(1-F_X(y-u))dy$

edit: second try of developing the second reasoning:

$\mathbb{E}(\text{max}(X-u,0))=\int_u^\infty(x-u)f_X(x)dx=\int_u^\infty\int_u^{x}1f_X(x)dydx=\int_u^\infty\int_{y}^\infty f_X(x)dxdy=\int_u^\infty(1-F_X(y))dy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $Y:=\max\left(X-u,0\right)$ it is clear that $Y$ is a nonnegative
random variable so that: $$\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{Y}\left(x\right)dx$$
For $x>0$ we find $1-F_{Y}\left(x\right)=P\left(Y>x\right)=P\left(X>u+x\right)=1-F_{X}\left(u+x\right)$
leading to: $$\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{Y}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{X}\left(u+x\right)dx=\int_{u}^{\infty}1-F_{X}\left(x\right)dx$$

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed correct, but is there a way to do that like my second reasoning?

Comment: Your second reasoning is making use of a PDF so that it only counts if the distribution is absolutely continuous. I have not checked it on errors yet.

Comment: I edited my second reasoning, hoping that I didn't do mistake because I got the answer

Comment: I think that your methods are both okay. I would not choose for the second though. Simply because there is not always a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, layer loss costs, or more precisely, excess annual aggregate loss (XSAAL) not conditional on being in the layer. Let $S(x)$ represent the survival function $1 - F(x)$.
$$
\begin{align}
E(\max(X - u), 0) &= \int_{u}^\infty(X - u) f(x)\; dx\\
&=\int_{u}^\infty Xf(x)\;dx - u\int_{u}^\infty f(x)\;dx\\
&=\int_{u}^\infty Xf(x)\;dx - uS(u)\\
\end{align}
$$

Use integration by parts on the first term. Let $t = x, dt = 1, dv = f(x), v = -S(x)$.
$$
\int_{u}^\infty Xf(x)\;dx = -xS(x)\biggr\rvert_u^\infty - \int_u^\infty -S(x)\;dx\\
$$
So the original expectation is now:
$$
=uS(s) - 0 + \int_u^\infty S(x)\;dx -uS(u)
$$
Outer terms cancel leaving us with:
$$
E(\max(X - u), 0) = \int_u^\infty S(x)\;dx
$$
The upper limit can also be a finite number, so the layer loss cost given an attachment point, $AP$ and a limit $L$ can be expressed the same way. Given $X$ is the random variable representing loss:
$$
E(\max(X - AP), L) = \int_{AP}^L S(x)\;dx
$$

Comment: sorry if I didn't precise that in the question, but I am trying to do that with double integrals because I would like to avoid integration by parts for this, it is not my favorite way to solve that. By the way this is also the numerator of the so called 'mean excess function' and yes I didn't condition because it's without the denominator

Comment: Understood regarding the IbP, and yes the mean excess function is conditional on being in the layer (what we actuaries would often call a TVaR assuming the upper limit is $\infty$.)

Comment: Why did you pick the anti-derivative of f(x) as -S(x) not F(x)?

Comment: Because it makes the math work better, especially as the right hand side of the initial equation already has S(x) in it.